# Принудительный вывод дат в DataFrame или форматирование в datetime

Tags: python, dataframe

Мой DataFrame отлично работает, но появилась необходимость импорта в в bigquery.
Импортирую, но столбца с датами нет.

В CSV, из которого я получаю данные, этот столбец есть.
Когда пытаюсь увидеть этот столбец с помощью dtypes, Ничего не выходит - выводится тип данных всех остальных столбцов.

Соответственно нужно как-то переделать столбец в timestamp либо в строки. При малейшей операции с этим столбцом выдается ошибка.
Стандартный метод решения (f['Date']=pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])) также выдает ошибку.

Код:

```
file=open("cashe.csv","w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
f=DataFrame.from_csv("cashe.csv",header=0,sep=' ',index_col=0,parse_dates=False)


f['Date']=pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
print(f.dtypes)
```

Входные данные:

Date    Impressions Clicks  Ctr Cost    AvgCpc  AvgImpressionPosition   AvgClickPosition    AvgTrafficVolume    BounceRate  AvgPageviews    ConversionRate  CostPerConversion   Conversions

2019-05-05  266628  4865    1.82    15587.98    3.20    4.65    2.28    87.34   18.15   1.12    91.88   3.49    4470

2019-05-06  348594  5700    1.64    24802.83    4.35    4.27    1.97    89.61   20.03   1.11    92.44   4.71    5269

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Столбец с датами у вас в качестве индекса? Попробуйте убрать `index_col=0` при чтении или сделайте `f.reset_index()`.

Comment: Без примера входных данных это гадание на кофейной гуще